addEventListener "click" or any other event is not working in ejs file
I have a select tag in ejs file,
\\html
 <label for="script">Choose a script:</label>
    <select name="script" id="script">
      <option value="main">Main</option>
      <option value="main2">Main2</option>
    </select>

I want a function to execute as soon as the value of the select tag is changed, I tried the 'onchange' event and it didn't work, so I tried 'onclick', but then I realised the eventlistener isn't responding at all no matter whatever the event type is, here's the code in js file -
\\JS
document.getElementById('script').addEventListener('onchange', ()=>{
    console.log("registered")
  })

However, if I use 'click' instead of 'onclick' and 'change' instead of 'onchange' everything works fine. So is there any difference when 'on' prefix is used?

Avoid using ambiguous names (like "script") for your variable names. Establish good habits now, this will help you avoid some unpleasant surprises tomorrow.

Sure, I'll go through and make all necessary changes to the names and structure of my code, once I figure out how things work, all these are just temporary names I've assigned to the variables for now.

Bad tactic, temporary names will only waste time later when you have to rename them. A classic solution is to choose "select-script" here, which allows you to find the origin of this element.

The event name doesn't begin with on, it's just change or click.
on is add at the beginning when you're creating the listener using an inline attribute in the HTML, e.g.


<select name="script" id="script" onchange="console.log('registered')">
  <option value="main">Main</option>
  <option value="main2">Main2</option>
</select>



or when you're assigning it as a property:


document.getElementById("script").onchange = function() {
  console.log('registered');
};
<select name="script" id="script">
  <option value="main">Main</option>
  <option value="main2">Main2</option>
</select>



